# Terminate Excel Application using OLE

Tags: c++, excel, c++builder, vcl, ole

How can I mannually terminate an excel application using OLE Automation?

I would like to do this in some exception handling so that an excel process does not remain running if a function throws an error.

Currently I use the below code to open excel:

`Variant excel = Variant::CreateObject("Excel.Application");`

Comment: I'm working with OleVariant's which is part of Delphi's comobj.hpp. so none of the below examples work yet.

Comment: I just tried it (created a small app which starts and stops excel) and it worked. I had to use CreateOleObject, though.

Comment: Can you put some code, I'm interested how you use CreateObject with C++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
OleVariant excel;

excel = Variant::CreateObject("Excel.Application");
//
// Your code
//
excel.OleProcedure("Quit");
```